# Reverse Proxy to local container

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, http, apache2

I need run Kafka on docker with web UI on some specific domain AND LINK, for example:

```
http://somesite.com/kafka
```

I am using this docker-compose.yml.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafka-ui:
    image: 'provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - '9099:8080'
```

When I set `apache2` by direct domain `kafka.somesite.com`, it is working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName kafka.somesite.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9099/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9099/
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try set domain with the link `somesite.com/kafka`, there is only blank screen.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName somesite.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /kafka http://127.0.0.1:9099/
  ProxyPassReverse /kafka http://127.0.0.1:9099/
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I make Kafka functional with link?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use an Nginx reverse proxy container?

Comment: Maybe Apache is already providing content or proxying to other services.

Answer (score 0):

ServerName should still be `somesite.com`, because Apache still expects that as base URL. When the URL is `somesite.com/kafka` it should redirect it to `http://127.0.0.1:9099/`

Bottom line, the second configuration should work as long as you set `ServerName somesite.com`

Comment: No, it is not working too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change two things. First, you need to configure the base URL of the kafka-ui container, you can do that using the [`SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH` environment variable](https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui#env_variables).

```yaml
# ...
  kafka-ui:
    image: 'provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=zookeeper:2181
      - SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH=/kafka
# ...
```

If you don't, all URLs generated by the kafka-ui will start at `/`, resulting in CSS, JavaScript and such being fetched from `/` instead of `/kafka/`.

Then you need to adapt the `ProxyPass` directive to that path:

```apache
ProxyPass /kafka/ http://127.0.0.1:9099/kafka/
ProxyPassReverse /kafka/ http://127.0.0.1:9099/kafka/
```

With `ProxyPass` always make sure your trailing slashes match, [as noted in the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing /, and vice versa. Otherwise, the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.